# Mailchimp mc-validate.js intercepts website's ajax request

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, syntax-error, mailchimp

Trying to embed a MailChimp subscription box in a WordPress powered website. The theme is custom made and loads most of its content via ajax.

When I insert the [provided script](https://s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.mailchimp.com/js/mc-validate.js) on the page, each ajax call is intercepted by mc's script which throws `Syntax error, unrecognized expression:` with the content of the reply pasted after.
This prevents the site from being displayed normally.

I can rewrite mc's ajax and avoid using this script altogether, but I would like to keep mc's validation.

Knowing what is used to intercept these calls would help me figure out how to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns Out I was simply missing this additional config to prevent conflicts with jquery.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
(function($) {
    window.fnames = new Array();
    window.ftypes = new Array();fnames[0]='EMAIL';ftypes[0]='email';
    fnames[1]='FNAME';ftypes[1]='text';fnames[2]='LNAME';ftypes[2]='text';
    fnames[3]='MMERGE3';ftypes[3]='text';fnames[4]='MMERGE4';ftypes[4]='text';
    fnames[5]='MMERGE5';ftypes[5]='text';}(jQuery));var $mcj = 
    jQuery.noConflict(true); // this seems to be the key
});
</script>
```